# how i can import font in my android?

Tags: android, unicode, special-characters, textview

I want to use unicode characters in my textview.How I import x.ttf?
And what is x?

```
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/x.ttf");
     getinput.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: it's just been 17 mins and you already demand and answer?!

Answer (score 0):

[ttf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) is a font format. x is the name of the file.
About how to import your specific font in to android app exist a lot of tutorials on the internet. [example](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-use-external-fonts-android)

Comment: I want to use unicode chars like "ç ı ş ö" and I need .ttf? if i need which ttf?

Comment: here http://www.1001freefonts.com/ you can download free fonts (but be careful, check if the font support unicode characters, usually they don't).

Comment: or go to you windows directory (C:\Windows\Fonts) and copy from there some standard font that support unicode (such as TimesNewRoman)

Comment: yes it is work when I move .ttf to fonts folder but still dont seen unicode?

Comment: I cant ask question anymore, please let me ask again